# How do I get my page to display the alert and unblur the image when the user clicks one of the buttons?

Tags: javascript, html, css, dom-events

so I'm working on a simple browser game right now, where the user has to guess who's being depicted in a blurry image displayed on the center of the page by pressing one of two buttons, and if the user guesses correctly, it displays an alert specifying whether they're right or wrong, and unblurs the image. However neither button is responsive when I click either one, so I'm wondering how I'd be able to actually get it to function properly.

I've tried this in multiple ways so far- during my first attempt, I wrote 10 divs of nearly identical code, aside from the id's on the image, which was supposed to indicate which guess was correct, and from there, after the user makes the guess, after a few seconds of displaying the image, the current div's display option is changed from "block" to "none", while the next div switches from "none" to "block"- so basically what I did for that, was assign the id's for each slide to a variable, then plugged each of those variables into an array, and I was trying to just get it to work like a slide show essentially. I wasn't really able to get it to iterate properly for that though, I also tried to get it to iterate from one sibling to another, so I decided that for now I would just settle for either just directing the user to a separate page with a different image and id indicator, or just replacing the image with the next one, and replace the id with the corresponding answer, and I also pasted the source code that I've written down so far into JS Fiddle just so I could see my progress in real time for the time being.

One thing that I've done so far, is that moved the indicator id, "isThing1" or "isThing2" for example, to the div tag rather than the image tag, and I also changed it from an id to a class- I'm not sure whether I'd be able to work with that a little bit easier or not- but since then I've decided just to return a function to each button, which has two built in anonymous functions that watch for clicks on button 1 and 2 respectively, and I've tried a method involving toggleBlur, another one that adds a separate class that unsets the filter, and now I'm just directly changing the filter attribute to "unset", by using the line image.style.filter = 'unset', and even that isn't quite working yet- I'm sure that any of those could've probably worked, but I'm thinking it has to do with what I wrote in each function, or how I've been referencing the event in the html code, because I also have an alert that's supposed to display as well, and that's not popping up. I'm also trying to set a timing function that starts onload, where the image is unblurred once the timer reaches 30 seconds, but that's working just as well as the onclick event. The styling and the HTML elements themselves look to be perfectly fine so far, it's just the JavaScript code that I haven't been able to figure out at the moment, so I'll include a generic template for the source code for the HTML, CSS and JavaScript just to give you a better idea:

```js
function guessingGame() {
  let image = document.getElementsByClassName('thing1OrThing2');
  let answer = document.getElementsByClassName('isThing1');
  let btn1 = document.getElementsByClassName('thing1');
  let btn2 = document.getElementsByClassName('thing2');

  btn1.onclick = function() {
    image.style.filter = 'unset';
    alert("Correct! It's thing 1!");
  };

  btn2.onclick = function() {
    image.style.filter = 'unset';
    alert("Incorrect! It's thing");
  };
}

  function timing() {
    let count = 0;
    let timer = document.getElementById('safeTimerDisplay');

    count = count + 1;
    timer.innerHTML = count;
    if (count === 29) {
      image.style.filter = 'unset';
      alert("Time's up!");
    }
  }
```

```css
body {
  background-color: lightseagreen;
}

#header {
  position: absolute;
  left: 50px;
  color: lightskyblue;
}

.thing1 {
  position: absolute;
  top: 340px;
  left: 155px;
}

.thing2 {
  position: absolute;
  top: 410px;
  left: 155px;
}

.or {
  position: absolute;
  top: 360px;
  left: 195px;
}

.thing1OrThing2 {
  position: absolute;
  top: 70px;
  left: 100px;
  filter: blur(1.2rem);/**Sets the initial blur of the image**/
}
```

```html
<html>
  <body>
    <div class='isThing1' onload='return timing();'><!--supposed to return timing function onload, class indicates the correct button input-->
      <h2 id='header'>Thing 1 or Thing 2?</h2>
      <p id='safeTimerDisplay'></p>
      <img src='http://3.bp.blogspot.com/-KpXH9T01SHc/T0y46Pu08MI/AAAAAAAABNk/8UtrnQ0SDSM/s1600/thing1_color.png' width='230' height='240' class='thing1OrThing2'>
      <button class='thing1' onclick='setTimeOut(guessingGame, 5000)'>Thing 1</button><!--supposed return the button input and display it for 5 seconds on click-->
      <p class='or'>Or</p>
      <button class='thing2' onclick='setTimeOut(guessingGame, 5000)'>Thing 2</button><!--supposed to return the button input and display it for 5 seconds on click-->
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Let me know if I've made any mistakes with the formatting on this post by the way, or if there's anything you need me to clarify a little bit on, I'll answer to the best of my ability. I don't post here very often, so I'm still a little green- as I am with my JavaScript at the moment apparently hahah.

Comment: Run the snippet above, and check the error message it displays.

Comment: The code you shared gives an error. Can you share the working code?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not a pro here but I'm gonna point out some things that might help you with your project:

1. The first issue I noticed is that you are using the getElementsByClassName method to get references to the elements you want to manipulate, but this method returns a collection of elements rather than a single element. To fix this, you can either use the getElementById method to get a reference to a specific element by its ID, or you can loop through the collection of elements returned by getElementsByClassName and add event listeners to each one.
2. You are also using the setTimeOut method to delay the guessingGame function by 5 seconds when the user clicks on one of the buttons. However, the correct method name is setTimeout, and you need to pass the function as a callback without parentheses, like this: setTimeout(guessingGame, 5000).
3. In your guessingGame function, you are trying to access the image variable and the answer variable, but these variables are not defined within the scope of the function. To fix this, you can move the variable declarations outside of the function so that they are in the global scope, or you can pass them as arguments to the function.